# how to prove $\operatorname{arctan}(x) > x/2 -x^3 /6 \:\:\: \forall x>0$

Tags: calculus

How can I prove  : $$\arctan(x) > \frac{x}{2} -\frac{x^3}{6} $$

when $x>0$ .

I don't know what to do  , please help .

I tried using Taylor but it didn't help me .

Comment: correct you $\LaTeX$ please

Answer (score 2):

Let $$f(x)=\arctan x -\frac{x}{2}+\frac{x^3}{6}$$

It's not hard to compute :

$$f'(x)=\frac{1}{x^2+1}-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{x^2}{2}=\frac{x^4+1}{2(x^2+1)}>0$$

This means that $f$ is strictly increasing .

But also note that $f(0)=0$ so $f(x)>0$ for every $x>0$ .

Comment: haha, we made the same thing.

Comment: It will take some time to be used to $\LaTeX$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Let $$f(x)\equiv \arctan x-\frac{x}{2}+ \frac{x^3}{6}.$$

$$\Downarrow$$

$$\frac{d}{dx}f(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^2}+\frac{x^2-1}{2}=\frac{x^4+1}{2(1+x^2)}>0,\:\:\forall x>0.$$

Answer (score 0):

If $f(x)=\arctan(x)-\frac{x}{2}+\frac{x^3}{6}$, it's easy to show that $f'>0$ and that $f(0)=0$. Therefore, you get the result.